# C++ broken_promise exception

Tags: c++

I'm learning about `std::async` and came across the `broken_promise` exception.

However, the following sample code doesn't seem to be causing the broken promise exception.
My understanding is that when the promise is destroyed and the future is still waiting, the exception should be thrown. However, in my code the call to `future.get()` waits forever.

Shouldn't the promise's destructor be called & the exception be thrown when the lambda is done?

```
int main()
{
    std::promise<int> prom;
    std::future<int> fut = prom.get_future();
    auto retFut = std::async(std::launch::async, [prom = std::move(prom)] () mutable {
        cout << "In child" << endl;
        //prom.set_value(4); <-- Shouldn't not having this line cause the exception
    });

    int childValue = fut.get();
    cout << "Child has set the value: " << childValue << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or even this program where the child is expecting a promise to be set

```
void DoSomething(std::future<int>&& fut)
{
    cout << "Waiting for parent to send a value " << endl;
    int val = fut.get();

    cout << "Parent sent value " << val << endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::promise<int> prom;
    std::future<int> fut = prom.get_future();
    auto retFut = std::async(std::launch::async, DoSomething, std::move(fut));
    // prom.set_value(3); <-- This should cause the exception?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Following the question, I am interested to see what the answer will be. That being said, `std::async` is a part of C++ that is best sidestepped. I surely hope it dies sometime soon, because it's simply inadequate, does not deliver in practice. It is, however, up to you how you spend your time.

Comment: What's the alternative? `packaged_task`?

Comment: The alternative is some kind of thread pool. There are some interesting open-source libraries that implement task executions on thread pools. For instance, `cpp-taskflow`.

Comment: When you have an explicitly defined promise and associated future, you typically use it along with std::thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary problem is that the wrong future is being waited on.

You are waiting on

```
int childValue = fut.get();
```

when you should be waiting on

```
int childValue = retFut.get();
```

That being said, `std::async` is a part of C++ that is best sidestepped. In practice, it rarely delivers and in complex projects it's better to use some kind of task pool, e.g., `cpp-taskflow`.

Comment: Updated the description with another case where I don't see the `broken_promise`. For the 1st case, the return value of `retFut.get()` is `void`. I think the example I have is valid albeit contrived.

Comment: You want to use a future that is not associated with any task. The same promise does not imply the same future.